# Adding a td for existing table using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I am trying to add a `td` for existing table using `jQuery`. But it's adding duplicate. How to validate exactly to add the `td`.

I have tried below code:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>head1</th>
    <th>head2</th>
    <th>head3</th>
    <th>head4</th>
</tr>
</thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr >
            <td class="test test2">a1</td>
            <td>a2</td>
            <td>a3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="test">c1</td>
            <td>c2</td>
            <td>c3</td>
        </tr>            
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**jQuery code**

```
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function() {

       for(i=0;i<2;i++){
         var row = '<td style="background: red">b_'+ i +'</td>';    
                $('[class="test"]').before(row);
       }

})
        </script>
```

I want to add a `td` where exactly match the `class="test"` is, but it's adding both `class="test test2"` and `class="test"`.

How can I do this?

Comment: use $('[class="test"]').before(row); instead of  $('.test').before(row);

Comment: @ magento two: try with this selector $('[class="test"]:eq('+(i)+')').before(row);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       var length=  $('[class="test"]').length;
       for(i=0; i<length; i++){
         var row = '<td style="background: red">b_'+ i +'</td>';    
         $('[class="test"]:eq('+(i)+')').before(row);
       }
});
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/Lqkmu7L1/